# batch file to list all txt files from other directories

Tags: windows

I am in the process of fetching all the .txt files from one directory to another (my current).

My current directory is

```
C:\USERS\MRAH
```

where i have the batch file and i have the code to fetch all .TXT files from the directory

```
dir E:\S_RUNS\12 month_STAR\S_2013\tst\*.txt /b >> INPUT_FILE_LIST.TXT
```

I am not able to fetch all the .TXT file which are in the E:\ DIREC into INPUT_FILE_LIST.TXT file on C:\USERS\MRAH

Can anyone let me know as to what should be code to fetch all the .txt file from one directory to another...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure this will work on multiple directories but you could try it.

```
Cd E:\[path]
for /d %%a in (*) do (if %~xa == .txt echo %%a >> input_list.tmp)
for /f %%a in (input_list.tmp) do (copy %%a C:\USERS\MRAH)
```

note the batch file needs to be run from the E:[path]
also note you save it as a .tmp file to prevent it from logging itself
also instead of making an input_list file do it directly:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (if %~xa == .txt copy %%a C:\users\MRAH)
```

Tell me if this doesn't work
Yours, Mona

Answer (score 0):

Assume your current working directory is c:\testDir and you wanna copy all txt files from c:\source to d:\dest then use following content in a batch file

copy c:\source*.txt d:\dest